# Black screen after suspending Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wakeup

Somewhat of a newbe, but know removing my HP-G62 battery fixes it each time.  My problem is similar to others, but I have not seen a clear solution, at least not lately.  Any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try update your kernel. You can following the steps in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) to update your kernel. I had the same issue before and when I updated the 3.90 kernel for raring everything works fine.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, you should include the steps needed to solve the problem in your answer.

Comment: Did you see the link? I think I'd better give my source credit rather than paste it here.